# Connecting to company VPN with my own PC - what can they see?

Tags: vpn

I recently started working from home a few days a week, and currently use my home PC to connect to the Company network. I use Citrix receiver to connect to my Company network then remote into my desktop at work.

I understand that whatever I do inside the Citrix receiver window they can see, not a problem with that. But what about what I'm doing on my PC outside the Citrix window? Can they see that I have Netflix open and what web pages I'm viewing?

Apologies for creating a new post but all of the one's I seen were where the OP was using a company provided device, this is my home device and only connected via Citrix receiver.

Comment: Depends if the rest of the traffic is going through the VPN or not (split tunneling). Most VPN systems are configurable in either way, so can't tell without knowing the config - therefore, I'd assume that they can see other traffic, since that's the fail-safe option (i.e. doesn't lead to lack of job if they can!)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the VPN used and I have never used Citrix. But AFAIK, VPN solutions commonly configure the network in a way that the machine is seen as *local* to the remote end of the VPN. That means that once connected to the VPN, all your network exchanges go through the VPN connection. Any other way would open an uncontrolled gateway between the internal network and the global internet.

All corporate VPN solutions I have used were that way: once connected, all network traffic goes through the VPN.

That means that your company should not know what files exists on your computer and for privacy reasons should not even try to know. But if you connect to Netflix once the VPN is on, it is likely that both the requests and responses pass through the VPN and the corporate proxy to internet. You should control what routes exists on your machine when connected to the VPN to confirm it, normally the command `netstat -r` can be used to show that.

Of course *encrypted* exchanges should normally not be decodable, but network admin generally abhor netflix requests through their network...

Comment: Not all VPNs act as described. Many will permit split tunneling (as mentioned in the comment above) to reduce load on the corporate network.

Comment: @JesseKeilson: I do agree with you, most VPN can be configured for split tunneling. But many network admins do not like that because it creates an uncontrolled internet acces for the internal network

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect that, unless you are being forced to install certificates on your browser (which would allow your company to initiate encrypted connections and decrypt and re-encrypt them as they pass by them) that all non-HTTPS connections can be seen.
As for HTTPS connections, I believe it's only the domain name that is visible, regardless of what content is being viewed through that domain.

China's CPC, for example, use to block specific Wikipedia pages, which was possible when Wikipedia didn't use HTTPS. Once Wikipedia went HTTPS, China's CPC couldn't satisfy it's hunger for control enough, no longer being able to block specific pages, and then outright blocked Wikipedia entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If their VPN team is evil (or good) the could set up responder to capture logins for every system you use.

You should look at the routes they are pushing, eg if they push default routes or only routes for the company network.

They will see that you open Netflix/Spotify/whatever when these applications use any route through the VPN.